# Select default value/object option

Tags: angular5, html-select

I have this `select` element that displays all products categories.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label">Category</label> 
   <select (ngModelChange)="setNewCategory($event)" [(ngModel)]="product.productCategory" name="productCategory">
   <option *ngFor="let category of productCategoriesPage?.content" [ngValue]="category">{{category.name}}</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

If I want to edit a product, I want to have its category pre-selected in the `select option` element. Is there something to add in html code or this should be made programatically (ts file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `compareWith` directive like follows :

```
<select [compareWith]="compareFn" (ngModelChange)="setNewCategory($event)" [(ngModel)]="product.productCategory" name="productCategory">
```

And :

```
compareFn(pc1: ProductCategory, pc2: ProductCategory): boolean {
    return pc1 && pc2 ? pc1.id === pc2.id : pc1 === pc2;
  }
```